# Searching Excels for common values and replace them

Tags: excel

I have two excel files.

With following columns

```
1st Excel 

Phone    comments


2nd Excel 

Phone    Address
```

Now I want to add comments column in the second excel by using phone. If phone from 1st exist in seoncd and is same then the comment column in added

I have been advised to use a VLOOKUP search, But I can't figure out how to do this thing. Any ideas will be appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this:

```
=VLOOKUP(A2, '1st Excel'!A:B, 2, 0)
```

`A2` is the phone number you're matching.

`1st Excel` is the name of the first excel sheet.

`2` indicates that the value you want to get is in the second column from column A, being the first, which contains what you want to pull from the first excel sheet.

`0` is the same as `FALSE`, and indicates exact match.

Comment: They must be in same folder i suppose?

Comment: @MuhammadUmar not necessarily. But if you mean your data are in different workbooks, then you can manually select the table. First make sure that both workbooks are open. Type in `=VLOOKUP(A2,` in cell C2 in 2nd Excel, then click on the 1st Excel, select the first two columns (you should get something like [this](http://i.stack.imgur.com/zIvLs.png) when you select the columns), then continue typing the `, 2, 0)`. Let me know how it works out! :)